# loading a new page without navigating from existing page?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

im having a JSP page on clicking a button it will open a new page ones it closed , i need to get the previous page .

i tried to open the new page using window.open (javascript)& closed using window.close, but im not getting the previous page.

Any solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: My recomendation is to start marking some of the answers you received from previous questions as accepted. Then you will get more answers to your questions in the future.

Comment: Any reason you need to pop up a new window? That's bad/unfriendly design. Just use `history.go(-1)` in the current window to go back to the previous page.

Comment: @Marc B, if i open the page using window .open , can i go back to the page using history.go(-1)

Comment: @kiran: You've asked a lot of questions besides this one, but you haven't marked any answers as accepted on any of your questions.  That will generally lead to fewer people paying attention to your questions.

Comment: i replied , for the answers that im accepted. i dont know about marking the answers.

Comment: no. the history object is per-window. a brand new window will have no history at all.

Comment: @MarcB, my situation is like, im adding some data, and i have an option to see the preview of the data . once i closed the preview page , i need to get the data adding page from wer i stopped ...

Comment: Maybe I'm lost but if Page A opens a new window that loads Page B, Page B does something and closes itself, you will still be on Page A.  What is the previous page you are trying to get?

Comment: @Nimrod : how to open that new page and how to close it if i use target="_top" attribute in <a > ta> tag , how can i close that one

Comment: With `target="_top"` the page will not open in a new window. It will load the page in the top-most frame when using frames. Otherwise, in most browsers, it will just load the page in the current window. Are you using frames?

Comment: @Nimrod, i tried with target="_parent" and it open in the top of the current window, but how can i close this window